# KeepAlive timeout is 5, but httpd processes are going for hours

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have a client's app running Apache, and woke up today to see it had a load average of 11.2 (!). There were numerous httpd processes running, all apparently having been going for hours, and chewing up all the CPU.

After restarting Apache, my load average is down to 0.4, and the issue seems to have disappeared.

Now, if my keepAlive timeout is 5, how do these httpd processes run so long? I don't really know how to diagnose what they're doing, and why.

It appears to have fixed itself in the short term, but that's pretty concerning cause I don't know when it'll be back, haha.

Answer (score 1):

KeepAlive and KeepAliveTimeout determine, how long the server will keep an idle connection to wait for another request from the client on that connection. There is no reason why the processes should use CPU time while waiting.

One apache process can serve many connections, so a high CPU time in itself is not an indication that this was used on a single request, although processes are restarted after a defined number of requests they served.

You could thy to find hints in the server logs.

If it happens again, try to find out what the processes are doing. Use strace on one of the processes, or attach with gdb and use the "where" command.